# How to reset position of p:dialog on show?

Tags: primefaces, dialog

I have PrimeFaces dialog, which is centered:

```html
<p:dialog header="Contact Information" widgetVar="companyAl"
          modal="false" position="center center">
```

When I open it using:

```js
PF('companyAl').show();
```

it will appear on the screen center.
However, when I drag it somewhere else, close it and reopen it again,
it will appear again in the last position before closing instead of
on the screen center. How to force it to appear always on the screen center after

```js
PF('companyAl').show();
```

?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could also simply add an `onShow` attribute to the dialog:

```html
<p:dialog header="Contact Information" widgetVar="companyAl"
          modal="false" position="center center" 
          onShow="PF('companyAl').initPosition()">
```

Comment: Sadly my dialog remains attached to the bottom: `<p:dialog
dynamic="true"
modal="true"
resizable="false"
header="#{project.ADMIN_SINGLE_PRODUCT_DETAILS_HEADER}"
hideEffect="fade"
showEffect="fade"
widgetVar="productDialog"
position="center center"
onShow="PF('productDialog').initPosition()"
responsive="true"
>`

Comment: @Roland Maybe it's one of your additional attributes. Have you tried to remove them step by step?

Comment: Hmm, you use `modal="false"`, I do `true`. I try it out this evening.

Comment: Guys, what if I'm opening a dialog from bean with `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog` ? How can I call `onShow="PF('widgetVar').initPosition()"`? I mean I don't have a widgetVar name

Comment: @SergeiK I didn't use the dialog framewort so far, but why you can't pass the onShow and widgetVar as parameters?

Comment: `initPosition()` works fine even with modal dialog, BUT if the dialog has a fade effect the position is initialized AFTER the fade so you see that the dialog moves.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the appendTo attribute:

```
<p:dialog id="yourId" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)" widgetVar="yourWidgetVar" header="#{msg.title}" draggable="false" resizable="false" >
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, @Jaqen H'ghar
thanks for answer!

When showing dialog is triggered by link, this will work:

```
<h:outputLink onclick="PF('companyAl').initPosition(); 
PF('companyAl').show(); return false;">click here to show company Al</h:outputLink>
```

Comment: You should answer in the comments and ask for correction and/or edit the answer by yourself. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Surround with a DIV:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 1px;">
  <p:dialog header="Contact Information" widgetVar="companyAl" modal="false">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<p:dialog header="my Header widgetVar="setPassDialog0" width="50%"
                style="width:20%;margin:0 auto" modal="true" showEffect="fade"
                hideEffect="fade" resizable="true">
```

Comment: In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.